# How to send downloading process as a background process

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am downloading data from my server it is taking like 5 to 6 minutes for downloading..while downloading I am not able to do any work in my application. How to send downloading process on background so that user can navigate within application and after download. we will inform user downloading completed..

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have your downloading code on a separate thread (NSThread on iOS). [Here's](http://www.xprogress.com/post-36-threading-tutorial-using-nsthread-in-iphone-sdk-objective-c/) a tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the new thread:

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) 
        toTarget:self 
        withObject:nil];`

1. Create the method that is called by the new thread:

`- (void)myMethod`
`{`

```
       NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

       /*** code that should be run in the new thread goes here ***/

      [pool release];
```

}

What if you need to do something to the main thread from inside your new thread (for example, show a loading symbol)? Use performSelectorOnMainThread.

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) 
    withObject:nil 
    waitUntilDone:false];`